# WPF Google-style ComboBox - AutoSuggestion

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, autosuggest

I want to have a Input field where I can input a string. That string could be a new item for that field or I choose to select an existing item. So I do not want Auto-Completion, but Auto-Suggestion which allows me to add entries to the `ItemsSource` by typing them in.

Basically it is like a normal WPF Combobox with

```
IsEditable="True"
```

But how can I get the ComboBox to reduce the list of suggestions to the string I input?

I don't want the ComboBox to present all Items of `ItemsSource` for selection, but only the ones that contain the string I input.

Can I do it due just setting some ComboBox properties?

Comment: You could use thrid-party control.Such as http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

For this propose you can use open source solutions like [WPF AutoComplete TextBox control](http://wpfactb.codeplex.com/) or other *Autocomplete* solutions

Answer (score 0):

For this, I use the DevExpress library. If the `ComboBoxEdit` is configured correctly, it will auto display a drop down list which is continuously filtered by what the user types. Make sure you set the `Mode` to `Contains`, so it matches on any part of what the user types. Users love it as they can quickly narrow down the list of items to select from.

For the record, I am not affiliated with DevExpress.  I'm sure Telerik has an equally good control as well.